# Naming a Process so i can kill it later on

Tags: c#, process

I have a Process I start off that will ping a host repeatedly using:

```
ping my_ip /t
```

I use this code to start it

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe");
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; 
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ping " + my_ip  + " /t";
process.Start();
```

Now, if my app is terminated unexpectedly i would like to close this 'PING' on restarting the app.

I could enumerate through the processes until I see the name 'ping' and kill it.

But being a pessimistic programmer there might be another Ping process started by another app so I would not want to kill that process.

is there a way to set the id of a process so that I can kill that process specifically?

i  am using C#

Comment: why not holding the reference to process variable and call `Kill()` when you want?

Comment: Hi, yes I can/will do that. I should have been more detailed in my question. If my app is terminated abruptly then I cannot rely on that mechanism.  My fault.  I will edit my question now :)

Comment: hi all, yes I knew i wouldget voted down for the typo. so wil have to close the question and reopen it .  thanks

Comment: if your application is terminated abruptly how can you terminate it then?

Comment: When it is restarted.

Comment: A process does not have a name, it has a number.  Provided by Process.Id.  It is not guaranteed to be unique forever, numbers get recycled if you don't keep a reference on the process.  You have one, it is the *process* variable.  Don't lose it until the Process.Exited event fires.

Comment: I cannot close my question! jeezz!

Comment: @hanss yes I know that. that was the point of my question which I posted incorrectly and now I am being beaten to death for it :)

Comment: how about saving the process Id after creating it somewhere and when application loaded check if that process is alive or not?

Comment: @AndrewSimpson you could use JobObjects, but that would require some p/invoking (I'm not sure there's a .NET framework wrapper for it). I've updated my answer

Comment: @dotctor process id's are not unique or exclusive. the id could have been taken by some other process

Comment: @dotctor hi, it was one of the ways I was thinking of it was just I wanted to not write external files if i can help it. But as you state it is a solution...

Comment: same process id, same process name, same arguments, what are the odds???

Comment: you can make it as a windows service too. stop and start it on application start. @AndrewSimpson

Comment: @dotctor all food for thought. I will a take a read on JobObjects 1st. Thanks for all ur commens

Comment: you can also use a thread instead of a process for a simple task like this. when application closes or terminated. it's threads will also terminated. @AndrewSimpson

Comment: @dotctor as it is the case with a ping, if the main application could be spawned several times, actually many chances of a duplicated id, name and arguments :-) I don't think programming "on odds" is correct :-)

If the outcome is a simple ping, then I agree with your last comment... you could just make a thread that pings the IP, and not call `ping.exe`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to name it. You have it already in the `process` variable. Just store this somewhere, then call:

```
process.Kill();
```

Whenever you are exiting your application

PS: Notice that you are using `process.WaitForExit();` this will block your application till the secondary process ends. Don't know why you have it there.

#### Update

As per the comments, you say that you may want to kill the process if your application is terminated unexpectedly.

Two things:

1) If your application is terminated in a non-deterministic way (fatal crash or something like that), then there's nothing you can do on your application's shutdown, thus you couldn't terminate the process even if it had a name.

2) Your `Process` variable has an `Id` field. You could store this on disk or something and try to kill it upon application re-startup. A warning though: processes id's are not exclusive... if your spawned `ping` has terminated (by any means), other process could have taken the same id. You can only be sure it was your original spawned process if you are controlling that process' termination.

As a possible solution to this, you can create a "Job Object" ([documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682409(VS.85).aspx)) using `JOB_OBJECT_LIMIT_KILL_ON_JOB_CLOSE` for its limit ([doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684147(v=vs.85).aspx)), and assign the child process to it using [AssignProcessToJobObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681949(v=vs.85).aspx), which would be make the child process by killed by Windows when your process terminates.

I don't think there's a .NET wrapper for Job Objects (I don't know of one), so it should take some P/Invoking and defining the structures, but it could be done.

Comment: Hi, it should not be there and I am an idiot twice over

Comment: hi, thanks for the info about jobobjevts. I will take a read!

Comment: @AndrewSimpson as dotctor stated in the comments... if you only need one ping, rather than doing all the pinvoking on job objects, I'd just make a ping in C# (which is rather easy) and have a background thread running on my app, instead of having the OS spawning a different process. You are applying a brute-force solution to a rather simple problem.

If you want a "general solution" which may involve any other processes (rather than `ping`), then you may want to invest your time in it

Comment: For reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping(v=vs.110).aspx